# Upgrading Layer 2 Switched Network to Layer 3

Tags: switch, vlan

I currently have a business network comprised of older but still fully working Layer 2 managed GigE switches. If I would like to have inter-vlan routing on this network (without having to setup a separate network router) would I have to upgrade all of the managed switches to Layer 3,  or does having one (it would be the central/main switch in a star topology network) Layer 3 switch in the network allow for inter-vlan routing without having to purchase all new managed switches throughout the network?

Thanks,

Comment: What type of device does the company use at the border to connect to your ISP? Is there a reason this device can't perform the routing that you need?

Comment: The answer to your question is more complicated than I needed to get into to ask my question and get an answer :)  There are multiple boarder gateway hardware devices,  some of which do not support inter-vlan routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need one Layer-3 switch to perform the routing, the others can stay as Layer-2.

However, if you wish to have multiple VLANs on a given Layer-2 switch, you should confirm that they support VLAN assignments and tagging.

Comment: The current layer 2 switches on the network are configured with multiple VLANs and working just fine.  Thank you!

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: VLAN tagging is a layer 2 function, and VLAN routing is a Layer 3 function.  The Layer 2 switches will "route" through the layer 3 switch that assigns the appropriate VLAN tags (is this right?)

Comment: *Any* routing is a layer 3 function; you can do it for physical ports, for VLANs, and for any combination of them: you assign one (or more) IP address(es) to an interface, be it physical or virtual, and then you tell the device to perform routing between those IP addresses; it doesn't really matter if routing happens between VLANs or physical ports. But your switch needs to operate at layer 3 in order to do *any* routing at all.

Comment: Yeah, VLAN tagging is a layer 2 function, but *routing*, of any kind, is layer 3 function. Layer 2 switches don't route, they just keep track out of which ports to forward packets for a particular MAC. A layer 3 switch will take those packets and route them to the next hop, be it VLAN, or another router. Also, there's not actually anything as a layer 2 or layer 3 switch; there are only layer 2 switches that have software which can operate at layer 3.

Answer (score -1):

Your device must be able to support layer 3. If that is the case, you can setup inter-vlan routing by creating layer 3 interface on one of the switch interface.

```
swA(config)#ip routing (to enable routing if it is disable!)

swA(config-if)#no switchport (making this port as a layer3 port.
```

After these commands, you can do the same config like a router's interface.

SUMMARY:

```
sw1(config)#ip routing

sw1(config)#int g1/1

sw1(config-if)#no switchport

sw1(config-if)#ip add 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0

sw1(config-if)#no sh

sw1(config-if)#end

sw1# wr me
```

Comment: What makes you assume the OP will get a cisco IOS based layer 3 swtich?

Comment: Also, he specifically asked about inter-VLAN routing; this is port-based routing. You need to add IP addresses to VLAN interfaces (`interface vlan X`), not to physical interfaces.